# How do you compare multiple variables to a certain data type in C++?

Tags: c++, termination

I have an assignment where I find the cost of shipping an item based on input from a file. One section asks me to terminate the program when an "An invalid character is present in the text file"

Expected output:

```
*************** File Read Error ***************
==> Reading of one or more package
==> parameters failed!!
==> Terminating program!!!
***********************************************`
```

My output:

```
    --------------------------------------------------
The package attributes are: 
Package type .................bulk
Total length .................45 inches
Weight .......................2111390112 pound(s)
--------------------------------------------------
The package rate factors are: 
Package Base Rate ............4.75 dollars
Length Factor Used ...........2.5
Weight Factor Used ...........4.5
--------------------------------------------------
```

Here is my Code:

```
        if (typeid(length) != typeid(int) || typeid(width) != typeid(int) || typeid(height) != typeid(int) || typeid(weight) != typeid(int)) // tests the type of these variables
    {
        cout << string(15,'*') << " File Read Error " << string(15,'*') << endl;
        cout << "==> Reading of one or more package" << endl;
        cout << "==> parameters failed!!" << endl;
        cout << "==> Terminating program!!!" << endl;
        cout << string(47,'*') << endl << endl;
        return 1;
    }
```

Here is the text file:

```
    // invalid character in height, width, length or weight
bulk
20
25
A15
25
```

Essentially, the program should terminate when it sees A15 because it has a char and expects just an integer.

Comment: Please post information as text, not images.

Comment: Don't give only links, provide relevant code directly in question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve] to show us *inside* the question itself.

Comment: `typeid(length) != typeid(int)` is compile time constant. it is independent of file content.

Comment: Just changed it all to text. Sorry.

Comment: If you try to read an `int` from a C++ stream (e.g. `std::ifstream`) and the input can't be parsed as an `int`, then the stream will set a state that you can check for.